# How to display Any items?

Tags: swift, xcode

How to display Any items ? The code provided returns an error.

```
func test() -> [Any] {
    
    let Num1 = Double(10.123456)
    let Num2 = Double(10.543221)

    let n1: [Any] = [Num1]
    let n2: [Any] = [Num2]

return [n1, n2]


}

let var = test()
print(var[0][1])
```

Error:
Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the return type to 2-D array:

```
func test() -> [[Any]] {
```